# grep pipe searching for one word, not line

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

For some reason I cannot get this to output just the version of this line. I suspect it has something to do with how grep interprets the dash.

This command:

```
admin@DEV:~/TEMP$ sendemail
```

Yields the following:

sendemail-1.56 by Brandon Zehm
   More output below omitted

The first line is of interest. I'm trying to store the version to variable.

```
TESTVAR=$(sendemail | grep '\s1.56\s')
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks

TESTVAR is just empty. Even without TESTVAR, the output is empty.

I just tried the following too, thinking this might work.

```
sendemail | grep '\<1.56\>'
```

I just tried it again, while editing and I think I have another issue. Perhaps im not handling the output correctly. Its outputting the entire line, but I can see that grep is finding 1.56 because it highlights it in the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ TESTVAR=$(echo 'sendemail-1.56 by Brandon Zehm' | grep -Eo '1.56')
$ echo $TESTVAR
1.56
```

The point is `grep -Eo '1.56'`

from `grep man` page:

```
   -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)

   -o, --only-matching
          Print  only  the  matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output
          line.
```

Comment: Just realized you can omit `-E` if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression doesn't match the form of the version. You have specified that the version is surrounded by spaces, yet in front of it you have a dash.

Replace the first `\s` with the capitalized form `\S`, or explicit set of characters and it should work.

Comment: Strange. Make sure that `sendemail` outputs that information to STDOUT (maybe it does STDERR).

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering: In your example you seem to know the version (since you grep for it), so you could just assign the version string to the variable. I assume that you want to obtain any (unknown) version string there. The regular expression for this in sed could be (using POSIX character classes):

```
sendemail |sed -n -r  '1 s/sendemail-([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+).*/\1/ p'
```

The `-n` suppresses the normal default output of every line; `-r` enables extended regular expressions; the leading 1 tells sed to only work on line 1 (I assume the version appears in the first line). I anchored the version number to the telltale string `sendemail-` so that potential other numbers elsewhere in that line are not matched. If the program name changes or the hyphen goes away in future versions, this wouldn't match any longer though.

Both the grep solution above and this one have the disadvantage to read the whole output which (as emails go these days) may be long. In addition, grep would find all other lines in the program's output which contain the pattern (if it's indeed emails, somebody might discuss this problem in them, with examples!). If it's indeed the first line, piping through `head -1` first would be efficient and prudent.

Answer (score 0):

```
jayadevan@jayadevan-Vostro-2520:~$ echo $sendmail
sendemail-1.56 by Brandon Zehm
jayadevan@jayadevan-Vostro-2520:~$ echo $sendmail | cut -f2 -d "-" | cut -f1 -d" "
1.56
```